# Scrapy problems with items file

Tags: web-scraping, path, scrapy, scrapy-item

**Hi there** I am learning Scrapy and now I am trying to use the file items.py

1. Firstly this is my Structure

[image]

inside of "items.py", I have the class named "SaraItem" where I am saving the information.
[image]

following the tutorial's suggestion," it says" I should use ***from .. items import CLASSNAME(created in items.py)***
however, I got the error no " No module named '**main**.items'; '**main**' is not a package"

I have been looking for some tutorials and they suggest

1. from SARA_WEBSITE.website_craw.items import SaraItem - No module named
2. from website_craw.items import SaraItem - No module named
3. Move the item.py to the same folder (to spiders folder)
4. use from sys import path and then add the directory - but it didn't work -
5. change my  Spider_module, NewSpider_module (actually now is 'sara.spiders')
6. from **future** import absolute_import -  ValueError relative import beyond top-level-package

I truly appreciate all your feedback and suggestions